# SEO practices for thumbnails

Tags: image, seo, thumbnails

There are SEO best practices to identify thumbnails with a filename prefix, suffix or other tips?

Comment: Just give your image a meaningful name. And for the img tag, include an alt tag and put the small description in there (keep it short).

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe there are any recommendations regarding file name prefixes or suffixes for thumbnails.

As far as all images are concerned (regular size or thumbnails), I would recommend putting meaningful description of your image content using `alt` and `title` attributes of `<img>` tag. Image names can sometimes be composed of some identifiers which are meaningless for customers. However, using meaningful image names is also recommended.

Please have a look at Matt Cutts Blog page: [Gadgets, Google, and SEO](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/matt-video-alt-attributes-for-images/) where Matt describes in details importance of correct informations in `alt` and `title` attributes of an image tag.